# Expectation of quadratic form of correlated variables

Tags: expectation, quadratic-forms

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are two $n\times 1$ dependent vectors, in the sense that
$E\left( UV^{\prime}\right) \neq \mathbf{0}.$ For a given constant $n\times n$ matrix
$A,$ is there is any simple way to calculate $E\left[ \left( U^{\prime
}AV\right) ^{2}\right] ,$ or even to find a upper bound and lower bound for this
quadratic expectation? Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Sorry to forget to mention that $A$ is symmetric and positive definite

Comment: If you are willing to assume extra conditions on $A$, like being symmetric, you can get some coarse bounds using eigenvalues. Otherwise, it really depends on the pairwise correlations of the entries as well.